# Apache Spark distance between two points using squaredDistance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dbscan, rdd

I have a RDD colletions of vectors, where each vector represent a point with `x` and `y` coordinates. For example, file is as follows:

```
1.1 1.2
6.1 4.8
0.1 0.1
9.0 9.0
9.1 9.1
0.4 2.1
```

I am reading it:

```
  def parseVector(line: String): Vector[Double] = {
    DenseVector(line.split(' ')).map(_.toDouble)
  }

  val lines = sc.textFile(inputFile)
  val points = lines.map(parseVector).cache()
```

Also, I have an epsilon:

```
  val eps = 2.0
```

For each point I want to find its neighbors who are within the epsilon distance. I do:

```
points.foreach(point =>
  // squaredDistance(point, ?) what should I write here?
)
```

How can I loop all points and for each point find its neighbors? Probably using `map` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
val distanceBetweenPoints = points.cartesian(points)
    .filter{case (x,y) => (x!=y)} // remove the (x,x) diagonal
    .map{case (x,y) => ((x,y),distance(x,y))}
val pointsWithinEps = distanceBetweenPoints.filter{case ((x,y),distance) => distance <= eps)}
```

You could also combine the distance calculation within the filter if you don't care about the distance between the points afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very new to Spark and trying to implement DBSCAN clustering algorithm using spark. This was the first step. Next step is to loop all points is to loop all points and do above mentioned procedure for all each point. In the algorithm I have to store the visited points - should I store them in separate array or use some pointer in Tuple to determine if it was visited?

Comment: Also I have other questions regarding implementation. Can I have your consultation where I could ask also another questions. For example, via Skype.

Comment: It is possible to have a private consultation? I would like to show you the code and get know what you think about it.

Comment: @Bob if you ask your questions here everybody benefits from it and you may get more than one opinion/view on your approach.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! Then I will post another question.

Comment: Please, have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577032/code-execution-inside-spark-foreach

Answer (score 2):

Even if this answer has been yet accepted, I put here as a notice that the accepted solution which is basically the same proposed in the github repo which has been suggested isn't really scalable due to the cartesian operation which has `O(n^2)` as complexity and with huge datasets this is definitely an issue.

There is another solution, i.e. another implementation of the DBSCAN algorithm over Spark which can be found here https://github.com/alitouka/spark_dbscan. This solution propose a different approach which partitions the RDD dataset into "boxes". In this way the near points can be only the ones in the same box of the point which is considered and the ones which are less than epsilon far from the bounds of the contiguous partitions. In this way, the complexity goes down to `O(m^2)` where `m` is `n/k`, with `k` being the number of partitions. Moreover other optimizations are performed (if you need further details you can read the code, contact the author or ask to me).

The previous implementations has some limitations: only euclidean and manhattan measures are supported and only dataset with very few dimensions can be successfully processed. To overcome this problems, I created this branch which aims to remove all these problems: https://github.com/speedymrk9/spark_dbscan/tree/distance-measure-independent. Now, it seems to work fine and all the problems are solved, though I'm going on and testing it in order to be quite sure it has no flaws before making the pull request.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [SparkAI library](https://github.com/aizook/SparkAI) and do something like:

`import org.aizook.scala.clustering.Spark_DBSCAN.DBSCAN
val cluster:Dbscan = new Dbscan(3,5,data)
cluster.predict((2000,(48.3,33.1)))`

with

```
`val data: RDD(Long,(Double, Double)
eps = 3
minPts = 5`
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input file? I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection exception.

Comment: @Bob That was because (48.3,33.1) does not fit a cluster and should be classified as noise. I provided some additional information hereafter

Answer (score 0):

@Bob That was because `(48.3,33.1)` does not fit a cluster and should be classified as noise.
I committed an update to the [SparkAI library](https://github.com/aizook/SparkAI) and it should return -1 anytime the prediction fits noise

```
import org.aizook.scala.clustering.Spark_DBSCAN.Dbscan
val eps = 2
val minPts = 2
val data = sc.textFile("data.txt").map(_.split(" ")).map(p => (p(0).trim.toDouble, p(1).trim.toDouble)).zipWithUniqueId().map(x => (x._2,x._1)).cache;
val cluster:Dbscan = new Dbscan(eps,minPts,data)
cluster.predict((data.count+1,(9.0,10.0)))  // Should return 1 for cluster 1
cluster.predict((data.count+2,(2.0,2.0)))   // Should return 0 for cluster 0
cluster.predict((data.count+3,(15.0,23.0))) // Should return -1 for noise
```

with data.txt containing the data sample you submitted:

```
1.1 1.2
6.1 4.8
0.1 0.1
9.0 9.0
9.1 9.1
0.4 2.1
```