# code execution inside Spark foreach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have two RDDs: `points` and `pointsWithinEps`. Each point in `points` represent `x, y` coordinate. `pointsWithinEps` represent two points and distance between them: `((x, y), distance)`. I want to loop all points and for every point filter only that elements which are in the `pointsWithinEps` as `x` (first) coordinate. So I do following:

```
    points.foreach(p =>
      val distances = pointsWithinEps.filter{
        case((x, y), distance) => x == p
      }
      if (distances.count() > 3) {
//        do some other actions
      }
    )
```

But this syntax is not valid. As far as I understand it is not allowed to create variables inside Spark foreach. Should I do something like this?

```
for (i <- 0 to points.count().toInt) {
  val p = points.take(i + 1).drop(i) // take the point
  val distances = pointsWithinEps.filter{
    case((x, y), distance) => x == p
  }
  if (distances.count() > 3) {
    //        do some other actions
  }
}
```

Or there is a better way to do this? Complete code is hosted here: https://github.com/timasjov/spark-learning/blob/master/src/DBSCAN.scala

**EDIT:**

```
points.foreach({ p =>
  val pointNeighbours = pointsWithinEps.filter {
    case ((x, y), distance) => x == p
  }
  println(pointNeighbours)
})
```

Right now I have following code, but it throws a NullPointerException (pointsWithinEps). How it can be fixed any why `pointsWithinEps` is null (before foreach there are elements in it)?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that for each point (x,y) on `points`, you want all ((x,y),distance) tuples from `pointsWithinEps` that originate on the same (x) ?

Comment: yes. Basically for each point I want to find which other points are its neighbors (points that are within the epsilon). In my case it is point itself and x in ((x, y), distance) structure. Code is in the github, so for example you can execute it and in debugger find exactly what are values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to collect all distance points that start on a given coordinate, a simple distributed way of doing that would be to key the points by that coordinate `x` and group them by that key, like this:

```
val pointsWithinEpsByX = pointsWithinEps.map{case ((x,y),distance) => (x,((x,y),distance))}
val xCoordinatesWithDistance = pointsWithinEpsByX.groupByKey
```

Then left-join the RDD of points with the result of the previous transformation:

```
val pointsWithCoordinatesWithDistance = points.leftOuterJoin(xCoordinatesWithDistance)
```

Comment: Compiler shows that there in no groupByKey method, only groupBy. The same also for leftOuterJoin method. I am using spark 1.1.0 pre-built for Hadoop 1.X

Comment: Also, should I put it into foreach loop?

Comment: These are  functions available on RDDs of (key, value) pairs through an implicit conversion. Import `org.apache.spark.SparkContext._` at the top of your program to use these functions.  - Also, there's no need for a loop. This functional pipeline gets the job done by applying transformations and grouping to the whole dataset.

Comment: Oooh, now I have groupByKey method, but I still do not have leftOuterJoin method. I do not understand where is leftOuterJoin method. Oooh, I understood, points are not of RDD type after reading from file and I cannot apply leftOuterJoin to them. How can they be converted to RDDs?

Comment: I assume that points is of the form `(x,y)` ?? The implict conversion is applied to RDDs of type `Tuple2` or a "pair" like `(x,y)`

Comment: see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63679/discussion-between-bob-and-maasg).

Comment: Yeah, but I parse them to double with parseVector method (see github code).

Comment: @Bob you can extract the x coordinate from the `Vector`. Looking at the API it seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring variables means you have a block, not just an expression, so you need to use braces `{}`, e.g.

```
point.foreach({p => ... })
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you also help with the functionality that I described?